# Regex for decimal prices with or without spaces

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I have a problem with my price regex which I'm trying to change. I want it to allow numbers like:

- 11111,64
- 2 122,00
- 123,12
- 123 345,23

For now I have something like this, but it won't accept numbers without spaces.

`'^\d{1,3}( \d{3}){0,10}[,]*[.]*([0-9]{0,2'})?$'`

I tried changing `( \d{3})` to `(\s{0,1}\d{3})` but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Try `'^(?:\d{1,3}(?: \d{3}){0,10}|\d{4,})(?:[,.][0-9]{1,2})?$'`

Comment: like this? `(?:[123456789]\d{1,2})(?:[ .]?\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?`

Answer (score 0):

All problems are easier if you break them into pieces.

First we have to match the non decimal
`1`
`100`
`1 000`
`10 000 000`

- The first grouping is 1 to 3 digits or `\d{1,3}`
- We still need to account for the following groups which may or may not be there. That in regex is a `*` or 0 or many `\d{1,3}(\s\d{3})*` in that second part we put a space in front of the set to it now looks for spaces between groups of 3.
- To complete this set we add in a `\d+` for a flat block of numbers
- Last we have to match the decimal, optionally `?`. `^(\d{1,3}(\s\d{3})*|\d+)(,\d+)?$`

```
  /^(\d{1,3}(\s\d{3})*|\d+)(,\d+)?$/.test(str)
```

Test it some more here: https://regex101.com/r/NKAVLk/1

Answer (score 0):

```js
[
  '1',
  '123',
  '11111,64',
  '2 122,00',
  '123,12',
  '123 345,23',
  '2 12,00',    // no match, pair of 2 digits
  '2 1234,00',  // no match, pair of 4 digits
  '1,123'       // no match, > 2 digits after comma
].forEach(str => {
  let t = /^(:?\d{1,3}( \d{3})*|\d+)(,\d{0,2})?$/.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' => ' + t);
});
```

Output:

```
1 => true
123 => true
11111,64 => true
2 122,00 => true
123,12 => true
123 345,23 => true
2 12,00 => false
2 1234,00 => false
1,123 => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start
- `(:?` -- non-capture group start (for logical OR)

  - `\d{1,3}` -- expect 1 to 3 digits
  - `( \d{3})*` -- expect 0+ patterns of space and 3 digits
- `|` -- logical OR

  - `\d+` -- expect 1+ digits
- `)` -- non-capture group end
- `(,\d{0,2})?` -- optional pattern of comma and 0 to 2 digits
- `$` -- anchor at end